# Regex find specific character but just when inside an HTML tag

Tags: regex

I have an HTML string, e.g. :

```
<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>some text “nice” here</a>
```

I'm trying to find out if any opening/closing double quote (`“”`, not `"`) is present inside an html tag (i.e. inside `<>`, but there could others things also in the tag).

In my example, `<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>` should match but `“nice”` or `</a>` shouldn't.

What is the right regex for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ok, found it : `<[^>]*[“”]+[^>]*>`

That does not work as you probably expect it to. When you add capturing groups, you'll see which parts of the string are actually matched by which groups:

```
<([^>]*)([“”]+)([^>]*)>
```

matches your example in this way:

```
<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>  a href=“{{foo.bar}}  ”
^ Full match            ^ 1st group          ^ 2nd group  ^ 3rd group (nothing)
```

Building on @Themelis' answer, you probably want to start with something like this:

```
<(\w+ [^<>“]*)“([^”]+)”([^<>]*)>
```

matches your example in this way:

```
<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>  a href=              {{foo.bar}}
^ Full match            ^ 1st group          ^ 2nd group  ^ 3rd group (nothing)
```

Comment: got it, makes total sense. I'm not a regex expert yet; thank you for the time you took to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't believe you've found it but you rather you fell into the common trap of regular expressions. You found a pattern which matches what you desire in a specific case.

If you place a `<` character inside the value of the tag of the link, `<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>some text < “nice” here</a>` and your regex will match `<a href=“{{foo.bar}}”>` **and** `< “nice” here</a>`.

So an extra caution needs to be taken when it comes to regular expressions. To match any opening tag of html better use `<\w+.*?>`. After that extract whatever you find inside `“”`.

Comment: I see, fortunately I did not have such specific case in my html file; And actually I did it that way because I also wanted to match cases such as e.g. `<“>` . But this is very unlikely; guess in the context of HTML tags what you explain here makes complete sense :) thank you very much for your help !

Comment: No problem mate